# Returning a variable from a listener function Javascript

Tags: javascript, return-value

I know variables are passed by value and objects are passed by reference, but can someone walk me through how to return a value after a listener has successfully been called and generated some data within a function?  Here's an example of a listener from the Chrome message passing API, assume there's another script somewhere returning a request.sentVariable:

```
var something = "";

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello") {
       something = request.sentVariable; ///*******************///
       sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    }
  });
```

The something variable needs to be updated by the data generated by the inner function and this isn't something where assigning the listener a variable and returning the desired data can work

```
var something = chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension" );
    if (request.greeting == "hello") {
      something = request.sentVariable;      ///**************///
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    }
    return something
  });
console.log(something);   ///****************///
```

So yea, I'm sure this is obvious stuff, but not sure at the moment.

Comment: No. You absolutely *cannot* `return` a value from the event listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem with asynchronous functions, before people grasp how they work. In your second code block, you

- define `something` to the result of `addListener`, which I believe is `undefined`,
- output that `something` (i.e. `undefined`)
- then some time later, the event gets triggered and `something` gets redefined to `request.sentVariable`. By this time, no-one cares.

You can't return a variable from an async function. It cannot be done. You need to use the variable inside the function, or in a callback that the function will be invoking.

Let me say this again, because it's that important:

> can someone walk me through how to return a value after a listener has successfully been called and generated some data within a function?

No. Cannot be done. Impossible. Never. Nope.

What you can do is this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension" );
    if (request.greeting == "hello") {
      gotSomething(request.sentVariable);      ///**************///
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    }
  });

function gotSomething(something) {
  console.log(something);
}
```

**EDIT:** If you need two different values coming from different event handlers, use either promises, or if you don't want to deal with a promise library, it is easy enough to implement yourself for simple cases:

```
var data1, data2;
var listener1 = function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  // ... -> data
  data1 = data;
  handleData();
}
var listener2 = function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  // ... -> data
  data2 = data;
  handleData();
}
function handleData() {
  if (data1 && data2) {
    // use data1 and data2
    // clear data1 and data2 so we can expect the next pair
    data1 = void 0;
    data2 = void 0;
  }
}
// set listener1 and listener2 as listeners
```

Comment: Say I need to work with two variables that come from two distinct listener functions that execute minutes apart...

Comment: Then use promises, or if you want to be more low-level and avoid promise libraries, implement a semaphore yourself.

Comment: I did. Look at my post again.

Comment: Sorry, I need some clarifications on your example, how does handleData() get both values if you don't pass them like this `handleData(data1);` and how does it have both values if the listeners are called minutes apart from each other... both of these are very counter intuitive from what I thought I knew about Javascript

Comment: In this example, `data1` and `data2` are either global, or scoped to a function enclosing the example. The idea is that after you get either `data1` or `data2`, you check if you have both of them, and if you don't, you wait till next time.

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it, I already knew this, LOL...  I was getting confused by something unrelated to this and just had a mental block.  Thanks.